# How can I get custom paging to work on a dynamically built HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, webforms

I have an issue with a dynamically built HTML table and custom paging. The result set is around 30,000 records and I would like to introduce custom paging. The table loads fine initially with 10 records showing but when I click the next button, all rows disappear. I'm sure it is something trivial but my javascript knowledge is not to great. Any help would be much appreciated

HTML Markup

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="AzureAutomation.Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
        <Scripts>
            <%--Framework Scripts--%>
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
        </Scripts>
    </asp:ScriptManager>

    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Welcome to the Microsoft and Proofpoint automation tool</h1>
        <p class="lead">Reset Session Tokens, Reset MFA Registration, and Reset / Lockdown Accounts, all at the click of a button</p>
    </div>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div id="userTablePlaceholder" clientidmode="Static" runat="server"></div>
        <button id="prevPage" clientidmode="Static" runat="server">Previous</button>
        <button id="nextPage" clientidmode="Static" runat="server">Next</button>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2>Reset Session Token</h2>
            <p>This will reset the session token of the selected user.</p>
            <p>
                <asp:Button ID="btnResetSessionToken" CssClass="btn btn-default" runat="server" Text="Reset Session Token" OnClick="btnResetSessionToken_Click" />
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2>Reset MFA Registration</h2>
            <p>This will reset the MFA registration of the selected user.</p>
            <p>
                <asp:Button ID="btnResetMFARegistration" CssClass="btn btn-default" runat="server" Text="Reset MFA Registration" OnClick="btnResetMFARegistration_Click" />
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2>Reset Account</h2>
            <p>This will reset the account status of the selected user.</p>
            <p>
                <asp:Button ID="btnResetAccount" CssClass="btn btn-default" runat="server" Text="Reset Account" OnClick="btnResetAccount_Click" />
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2>Lockdown Account</h2>
            <p>This will completely lockdown the account of the selected user.</p>
            <p>
                <asp:Button ID="btnLockdownAccount" CssClass="btn btn-default" runat="server" Text="Lockdown Account" OnClick="btnLockdownAccount_Click" />
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
            // Initial page index and page size
            var pageIndex = 0;
            var pageSize = 10;
            var totalRecords = <%= this.TotalRecords %>; // Assuming 'TotalRecords' is the total count returned from the server-side method
            var maxPageIndex = Math.ceil(totalRecords / pageSize) - 1;

            // Initial page display
            showPage(pageIndex, pageSize);
            updateButtonState();

            // Handle page navigation
            document.getElementById("nextPage").addEventListener("click", nextPageHandler);
            document.getElementById("prevPage").addEventListener("click", prevPageHandler);

            // Function to show/hide rows based on current page
            function showPage(pageIndex, pageSize) {
                var rows = document.querySelectorAll("#userTable tbody tr");
                var start = pageIndex * pageSize;
                var end = Math.min(start + pageSize, rows.length); // Ensure end does not exceed the total number of rows

                for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                    rows[i].style.display = (i >= start && i < end) ? "" : "none";
                }
            }

            // Function to handle next page button click
            function nextPageHandler() {
                event.preventDefault();
                if (pageIndex < maxPageIndex) {
                    pageIndex++;
                    showPage(pageIndex, pageSize);
                    updateButtonState();
                }
            }

            // Function to handle previous page button click
            function prevPageHandler() {
                event.preventDefault();
                if (pageIndex > 0) {
                    pageIndex--;
                    showPage(pageIndex, pageSize);
                    updateButtonState();
                }
            }

            // Function to update button state
            function updateButtonState() {
                document.getElementById("prevPage").disabled = (pageIndex === 0);
                document.getElementById("nextPage").disabled = (pageIndex === maxPageIndex);
            }
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

Code behind

```
using AzureAutomation.API;
using AzureAutomation.Helpers;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Logging;
using Logging.NLog;

namespace AzureAutomation
{
    public partial class Default : Page
    {
        public int TotalRecords { get; set; }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                var (searchResults, totalRecords) = UsersController.LoadActiveDirectoryAccounts();
                string userTableHtml = GenerateUserTable(searchResults, pageIndex: 0, pageSize: 10);
                userTablePlaceholder.InnerHtml = userTableHtml; // userTablePlaceholder is a placeholder for the HTML table in your Default.aspx
                TotalRecords = totalRecords;
            }


        }

        private string GenerateUserTable(List<SearchResult> searchResults, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
        {
            StringBuilder htmlBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            // Start the table
            htmlBuilder.Append("<table id='userTable' clientidmode='Static' class='table table-bordered table-striped'>");
            htmlBuilder.Append("<thead><tr><th>User Principal Name</th><th>Display Name</th><th>SamAccount Name</th></tr></thead>");
            htmlBuilder.Append("<tbody>");

            // Calculate the start and end indexes for the current page
            int startIndex = pageIndex * pageSize;
            int endIndex = Math.Min(startIndex + pageSize, searchResults.Count);

            // Loop through the subset of searchResults for the current page and add rows to the table
            for (int i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++)
            {
                var result = searchResults[i];
                htmlBuilder.Append("<tr>");
                htmlBuilder.Append("<td>").Append(result.Properties["userPrincipalName"][0]).Append("</td>");
                htmlBuilder.Append("<td>").Append(result.Properties["DisplayName"][0]).Append("</td>");
                htmlBuilder.Append("<td>").Append(result.Properties["samaccountname"][0]).Append("</td>");
                htmlBuilder.Append("</tr>");
            }

            // End the table
            htmlBuilder.Append("</tbody></table>");

            return htmlBuilder.ToString();
        }


    }
}
```

Data retrieval

```
public static (List<SearchResult> searchResults, int totalRecords) LoadActiveDirectoryAccounts()
    {
        List<SearchResult> allResults = new List<SearchResult>();
        var OUSplitList = OuList.Split('|').ToList();
        int totalRecords = 0; // Initialize the total count variable

        try
        {
            foreach (var OU in OUSplitList)
            {
                _logger.Info($"Loading AD accounts from {OU}");
                using (var dirEntry = GetDirectoryEntry(OU))
                {
                    string[] loadProps = { "DisplayName", "samaccountname", "userPrincipalName" };

                    using (var dirSearch = new DirectorySearcher(dirEntry, "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))", loadProps))
                    {
                        dirSearch.PageSize = 1000;
                        dirSearch.Sort = new SortOption("samaccountname", SortDirection.Ascending);
                        var results = SafeFindAll(dirSearch);

                        allResults.AddRange(results);
                        totalRecords = allResults.Count; // Increment the total count by the count of results
                    }
                }
                _logger.Info($"Accounts loaded - {allResults.Count} ");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }

        return (allResults, totalRecords); // Return both the list of search results and the total count
    }

    private static DirectoryEntry GetDirectoryEntry(string domain)
    {
        return new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + domain, Globals.IamUser, Globals.IamPassword);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<SearchResult> SafeFindAll(DirectorySearcher searcher)
    {
        using (SearchResultCollection results = searcher.FindAll())
        {
            foreach (SearchResult usr in results)
            {
                yield return usr;
            }
        } // SearchResultCollection will be disposed here
    }
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+asp+paging+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Ok I see. I was under the assumption that you were trying to hide and show rows of pages that you already rendered to the DOM. But your `GenerateUserTable()` backend function only runs once on page load? When does this get called again for subsequent paginated pages?